# Emojis are wider than enclosing <span> tag when font is small

Tags: html, css, emoji

In Chrome on Mac OS X, I have noticed that emojis don't scale down very gracefully. This is what I see:

[image: Emoji scaling width demonstration]

Other browsers may have this problem as well; I've created an example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/p2pjLd9m/

The checkered flag stretches the enclosing `<span>` tag in the two larger examples, but in the 10px/15px examples, the flag extends beyond the border of the span.

Is there a way to force the span to cover the width of the text as displayed?

Adding a right padding to the span isn't ideal, because I won't always know beforehand whether the span will contain an emoji or a Latin character.

Increasing the font size isn't ideal either, because I don't want to grow the text vertically. I just want the span to cover the emoji as it does with the larger font sizes.

**Edit**

This problem is more localized than I initially thought -- I have only been able to recreate these results in Chrome v55 & v56 on Mac OS X 10.12.2. Both Firefox and Safari render the span correctly. I will file a bug.

Comment: Try applying `display: inline-block;text-align: center;` for each span - Might help

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: @zer00ne Yes, I did. Thanks for your submission, but unfortunately, I am still seeing the issue, even with `ch` units.

Comment: @BillyBBone I  see it's ok on my Mac... Mine is about 3 years old.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not seeing the same issue using Mac and Chrome in your Fiddle, but you might want to try adding display: inline-block to your style for the span and see if that resolves your issue.